# Convert UNC path to the network system's Local path

Tags: c++, mfc

In my application, I am accessing an image on a network system. I want to know the Local path relative to that network system.

For example image is located at `\\192.203.65.34\Images\Image1.jpg` then I want to get the local address of that image on that system. This should return me lets say `D:\Images\Image1.jpg`

How do I do that in C++/MFC?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. It's not even certain that a local path *exists*.